# Specific inputs of experiment return parser error

Tags: bash, macos, shell, bc, optimathsat

```
#!/bin/bash
for tracelength in 50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500 ; do
    step=0.2
    short=0
    long=1
    for i in {1..4}; do
    ratio=0
        for j in {1..4}; do
                declare -a listofresults
                echo "$tracelength $short $long $ratio" >> results.csv
                python3 main.py "$tracelength" "$short" "$long" "$ratio">file.smt2
                chmod 775 file.smt2
                declare total=0
                declare m=0
                for repeat in {1..10}; do
                    executiontime=$(timeout 500 gtime -f "%U" /Users/ouafaelachhab/Desktop/SemanticLocality/optimathsat-1.6.2-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat < file.smt2 2>&1 >/dev/null)
                    echo "$executiontime"
                    total=$(echo "scale=2; ($total) + ($executiontime)" | bc) #echo $(bc <<< "scale=2; $total/100")
                    echo "$total"
                    let "m=m+1"
                    echo "m=$m"
                done
                echo $(bc <<< "scale=2; ($total)/10") >> results.csv
                ratio=$(echo "scale=10; ($ratio) + ($step)" | bc) #float points arithmetics are different
            done
            short=$(echo "scale=10; ($short) + ($step)" | bc)
            long=$(echo "scale=10; ($long) - ($step)" | bc)
        done
    done
```

I am basically just running an experiment where I run a file with variant inputs. The code works for some values and for some it just gives me:

```
(standard_in) 1: parse error
```

In my results file this is the output I have:

```
50 0 1 0
21.82
50 0 1 .2
27.08
50 0 1 .4
40.89
50 0 1 .6
```

The experiment I am running always stops at the same input values(the last one printed in the output file) and then from there it's all **parser errors**! why does it do that? and how do I fixe it? I have tried multiple solution I found for similar questions(related to bc) here but none worked.

Comment: So which values does it fail for and what's the input to `bc` in those cases?

Comment: it's there! the last value in the input file: 50 0 1 0.6 it produces parser error and from there it's all parser errors

Comment: I meant to say *output file

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have five commands like `echo "something" | bc` and of course they work by building and expression and passing it to `bc`. Can you find which particular line produces this error, and what the string you write to bc is? `bash -x yourscript` is one verbose way to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's related to the following line:

```
executiontime=$(timeout 500 gtime -f "%U" /Users/ouafaelachhab/Desktop/SemanticLocality/optimathsat-1.6.2-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat &1 >/dev/null)
```

When I change your code with

executiontime="ISSUE"

I get this as output (notice how I S S U E is being printed line by line)

```
m=3

ISSUE

(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: I
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: S
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: S
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: U
```

Comment: do you get the expected format at   echo "$executiontime" ?

Comment: The following line must be corrected .. `executiontime=$(timeout 500 gtime -f "%U" /Users/ouafaelachhab/Desktop/SemanticLocality/optimathsat-1.6.2-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat < file.smt2 2>&1 >/dev/null)` as it roughtly equivalent to `executiontime=$(something 2>&1 > /dev/null)`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: executiontime=$(something 2>&1 /dev/null) will always give executiontime="" ... as stderr (file descriptor 2) and stdin (file descriptor 1) are bound together using "2>&1" and then their output is sent to /dev/null, which mean "discarded" by the kernel.